# Не подследственно или неподследственно?

Tags: орфография

"Данное дело им не подследственно" — последнее слово с -не- написано верно?

Comment: У Д.Розенталя есть конкретное правило: "Частица НЕ пишется слитно, если в предложении содержится утверждение, и раздельно, если содержится отрицание". В данной фразе налицо отрицание.

Comment: Дурацкое правило. И интерпретировано оно, как мне кажется, не совсем верно.

Comment: Правило-то нормальное.  
Вот насчет интерпретации...

Comment: Это правило относится к качественным прилагательным, существительным и наречиям на -О (Е). образованным от качественных прилагательных. Осталось определить часть речи. Сомневаюсь, что подследственный - качественное прилагательное.

Comment: Фактически оно относится ко всем определениям, кроме, разве, местоименных притяжательных. Только "как правило" формулируется именно для качественных прилагательных, для остальных случаев почему-то вместо суть подменяется практическим приёмом, основанном на  наличии или отсутствии зависимых слов.

Вот, http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56 посмотрите, сколько всякого рода оговорок приглось сделать на grammа.ru при формулирофании "простыми словами" этого правила о зависимых словах.

А ведь все они, если вдуматься, сводятся именно к появлению/непоявления нового качества.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, думаю, да. Просматривается раздельное написание.
Речь идет об отрицании факта подследственности, а не о каком-то качестве самого дела.
Опять же наличие т.н. "зависимых слов" о том же свидетельствует. Хотя этот признак не абсолютный, но вполне действенный.

Comment: Соглашусь. Скорее раздельно, чем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь слово "им" решающее для раздельного написания. *Данное дело неподследственно* (не подлежит следствию или не находится под следствием) -- так писалось бы слитно.

Comment: Не уверен. Со стороно оно, конечно, именно так и выглядит, но дело в том, что подследственность - термин, понятный юристам. А вот является ли таковым "непоследственность" я не могу сказать наверняка. Скорее всего даже в этом случае речь идет об отрицании подследственности.  
Впрочем, ещё вернее, что без указания кому, сама фраза лишена смысла.

Comment: Действительно не знаю, есть ли такой термин "неподследственный", тем более в сочетании с делом (чисто как филолог предположила). Скорее всего дело может быть подследственно только кому/чему и не подследственно кому/чему, в любом случае раздельное написание НЕ. По словарю, "подследственность" - компетенция ведомства в досудебном расследовании, другие значения не беру во внимание. Но встретила слово "неподследственность" (http://grani.ru/opinion/abarinov/m.198510.html) в значении, если не ошибаюсь, безнаказанность в криминальном плане (ну, это так, между прочим).